# If input empty, no insert in mysql (pdo)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

If any of input fields is blank, then do not insert in mysql. It is possible (acceptable) that some of input fields are blank. In such case I need to insert non blank fields (values). But the script does not insert at all.

I can write something like

```
if ( (strlen($date_day1) < 1) ) {
$date_day1 = 0;
}
```

But may be better solution? If empty input field, insert all other fields. Empty field may not insert or inser 0.

Input

```
<input type="text" name="date_day1" id="date_day1"</td>
<input type="text" name="amount1" id="amount1"</td>
<input type="text" name="row_id1" id="row_id1"</td>
```

Then ajax get input values

```
$(document).ready(function(){
autosave();
});
function autosave() {
var t = setTimeout("autosave()", 5000);
var date_day1 = $("#date_day1").val();
var amount1 = $("#amount1").val();
var row_id1 = $("#row_id1").val();
$.ajax( {
type: "POST",
url: "_autosave.php",
data: "date_day1=" + date_day1 + "&amount1=" + amount1+ "&row_id1=" + row_id1,
cache: false,
} );
}
```

Then php get variables

```
$date_day1 = $_POST['date_day1'];
$amount1 = $_POST['amount1'];
$row_id1 = $_POST['row_id1'];
```

And then try to record in mysql

```
$stmt_insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO 2_1_journal(RecordDay, Amount, RowId) VALUES(:RecordDay,:Amount,:RowId)");


$stmt_insert->execute(array(':RecordDay' => $date_day1, ':Amount' => $amount1, ':RowId' => $row_id1,
```

));

**Update**

With such changed ajax insert works, but this does not work 
`success: function(){ document.getElementById('is_row_changed1').value = 0;}`

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
autosave();
});
function autosave() {
var t = setTimeout("autosave()", 5000);
var date_day1 = $("#date_day1").val();
var amount1 = $("#amount1").val();
var row_id1 = $("#row_id1").val();

if ($("#is_row_changed1").val() > 0) {
$.ajax( {
type: "POST",
url: "_autosave.php",
dataType: "json",
data: {"date_day1" : date_day1, "amount1" : amount1, "row_id1" : row_id1},
cache: false,

success: function(){
document.getElementById('is_row_changed1').value = 0;
}

} );

}
}
```

Comment: Typo: `$row_id_1` is not the same as `$row_id1`. That's probably why the database refuses to store the record...it has no ID.

Comment: No, no row_id_1 is my mistyping here. Everywhere is row_id1

Comment: Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` to your code to see whether there was an error executing your insert statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ajax portion and this will work:

```
$.ajax( {
type: "POST",
url: "_autosave.php",
dataType: "json",
data: {"date_day1" : date_day1, "amount1" : amount1, "row_id1" : row_id1},
cache: false,
} );
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, it helps, but then this does code not work success: function(){
document.getElementById('is_row_changed1').value = 0;
}. I will modify my code in question

Comment: @user2232696 ok, so remove `dataType: "json",` code from the ajax request. well where is your `s_row_changed1` field.

Comment: Thank you, all works! Could you advice what the dataType: "json", does (impact) here? Why below code does not work with dataType: "json",?

Comment: @user2232696 Yes, I can explain. the json datatype is the javascript object notation in which we convert the data into an object means bind the data of javascript in an object to send the data. If you use it then it is require to receive the return data also in json. the json format is very simple as you can see in data variable that I have used.

Answer (score 1):

To add non blank values, try this

```
$date_day1 = (trim($_POST['date_day1'])!="" ? $_POST['date_day1'] : 0);
```

In same way you can test if the other fields are empty and add default value and pass these variables to the query.